# Наследование/геттеры

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Геттер не выводит данные

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Tech
{
    string name;
    int value;
    string company;
public:
    Tech() { name = "PS4"; value = 1000; company = "Sony"; }
    Tech(string name, int value, string company);
    void setN(string n) { name = n; }
    string getN() { return name; }
    void setV(int v) { value = v; }
    int getV() { return value; }
    void setC(string c) { company = c; }
    string getC() { return company; }
};

class Mothercard : public Tech
{
    string connectorType; // тип разьема
    string formfactor; // формфактор
    string supportMemory; // поддержка памяти
    int countChannels; // кол-во канналов
    string chipSet; // чипсет
 public:
    Mothercard() {
    setN("Asus H110M-K"); setC("Asus"); setV(1555); connectorType = "Socket 1151";
    formfactor = "MicroATX"; supportMemory = "DDR4 DIMM"; countChannels = 2; chipSet = "Intel H110";
    }
    Mothercard(const string n, const string c, int v, const string connector, const string formf, const string supportM, int channels, const string chip);
    string getConType() { return connectorType; }
};

Mothercard::Mothercard(string n, string c, int v, string connector, string formf, string supportM, int channels, string chip)
{
    setN(n);
    setC(c);
    setV(v);
    connectorType = connector;
    formfactor = formf;
    supportMemory = supportM;
    countChannels = channels;
    chipSet = chip;
}     

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    Mothercard mothercards[5]
    {
    Mothercard("Asus H110M-K", "Asus", 1543, "Socket 1151", "MicroATX", "DDR4 DIMM", 2, "Intel H110"),
    Mothercard("Gigabyte B450 Aorus Elite", "Gigabyte", 3115, "Socket AM4", "ATX", "DDR4 DIMM", 2, "AMD B450"),
    Mothercard("Asus Prime Z370-P II", "Asus", 3804, "Socket 1151", "ATX", "DDR4 DIMM", 2, "Intel Z370"),
    Mothercard("Asus Prime H310M-K", "Asus", 1752, "Socket 1151", "MicroATX", "DDR4 DIMM", 2, "Intel H310"),
    Mothercard("Asus Prime B450-PLUS", "Asus", 2853, "Socket AM4", "ATX", "DDR4 DIMM", 2, "AMD B450")
    };

    cout << "Имя\t\t\t : " << mothercards[0].getN() << "\nЦена\t\t\t : 1 543 грн\nТип разъема\t\t : " << mothercards[0].getConType() << "\nФормфактор\t\t : MicroATX\nПоддержка памяти\t : DDR4 DIMM\nКоличество каналов\t : 2\nЧипсет\t\t\t : Intel H110" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибка:

E0349:  отсутствует оператор "<<", соответствующий этим операнда

C2679   бинарный "<<": не найден оператор, принимающий правый операнд типа "std::string" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменяйте:

```
#include <iostream>
```

На это:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```

Comment: Мда, это действительно меня выручило, но почему если написать #include <string.h> ошибка не исчезнет? В чем разница между string и string.h? Большое, спасибо!

Comment: @AlexFox https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257665/difference-between-string-and-string-h

Comment: @Alex Fox: "Разница" между ними в том, что *между ними нет вообще ничего общего*. Ваш вопрос бессмыслен. Это совершенно разные, никак не связанные друг с другом заголовки.

Comment: <string> заголовок для работы с std::string, <string.h> для даботы с си строками.